# Drupal image button with theme_image_style

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working in Drupal 7 and I have a specific request.

I have a form with several image buttons with acting as graph bars. I have a code similar to this:

```
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    $form['graph'][$value] = array(
        '#type' => 'image_button',
        '#name' => $value,
        '#src' => file_create_url($vars[$key]['logo]),
    );
}
```

where $vars[$key]['logo] is for instance **public://file_1.png** etc. and it works perfectly.

The trouble is i have to print out the same image buttons, but rotated by 90 degrees. 
I've tried to add an image style (logo_rotate) and then to do something like

```
  foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        $form['graph'][$value] = array(
            '#type' => 'image_button',
            '#name' => $value,
            '#src' => theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'logo_rotate', 'path' => $vars[$key]['logo'])),
        );
    }
```

This fails because theme function prints out a fully HTML formatted image like following:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo_rotate/public/file_1.png?itok=Y9hQtYZT" alt="" />
```

and the '#src' property of an image_button type requires an URL to the file.

Only idea i have is to explode the `<img>` tag string to get the src value.

Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is logo_rotate? Is it a directory, where the images, rotated by 90 degrees are stored. Please, explain, what "src" you want to get for the rotated image.

Comment: 'logo_rotate' is the machine name of the image_style which i want to apply. I want the 'src'  value of `<img>` tag (in this case: `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo_rotate/public/file_1.png?itok=Y9hQtYZT`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Drupal API [theme_image_size](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) use this function

`image_style_url($style_name, $path)`

to build the URL for an image derivative given a style and image path.

I think this is what you need :)

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I've found this function already, but since i'm a newbie here, i wasn't able to answer my own question for 8 hours upon the question was posted and you got it right in the meantime. Thank you kind sir for your effort to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that you need to use a theme function for such a simple task.

We know, that call to function `file_create_url("public://file_1.png")` returns:

```
http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/file_1.png
```

Just pass the different parameter to `file_create_url`:

```
file_create_url("public://styles/logo_rotate/public/file_1.png")
```

and you'll get, what you need.

### Code for replacement in the loop

```
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    $src = preg_replace('/^public:\/\/(.*)/', 'public://styles/logo_rotate/public/$1', $vars[$key]['logo']);
    $src = file_create_url($src);
    $form['graph'][$value] = array(
        '#type' => 'image_button',
        '#name' => $value,
        '#src' => $src,
    );
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem, if i had two different images, but this needs to happen on the run, that is why i use theme function. One other solution is to hook on node save or update and to make a duplicate rotated (export it to a physical file) but then i would have to take care of the old files etc.

Comment: @SrdjanMarjanovic I added some code for replacement of the src in the loop. Try it. It would be better, if $vars[$key]['logo'] didn't have the prefix "public://" at the beginning - no preg_replace call would be needed then.

Comment: Please kindly note that this is a Drupal 7 situation. In Drupal, public://filename.ext, when called as file_create_url('public://filename.ext') would return an absolute path to, lets say, http://example.com/site/default/files/filename.ext. I have founded a solution, but i have to wait 8 hours to post it as an answer, because i'm a newbie here :) Thanks for your effort to help me, though